# Hide Ribbon tabs on SharePoint list forms

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, ribbon

I am trying to hide all ribbon tabs in my SharePoint site(check the below image).

I am using delegate control with following piece of code. The code hides ribbon tabs on all the site pages, but not list forms.

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
if (!web.UserIsSiteAdmin)
{
   SPRibbon current = SPRibbon.GetCurrent(this.Page);
   if (current != null)
   {
      current.CommandUIVisible = false;
   }
}
```

I also tried following piece of code to see if I can hide the entire ribbon only on the list form by checking for existence of list form specific tabs, display form for example, but current.IsTabAvailable(SPRibbon.ListFormRibbonDispTabId)) returns false.

```
if (current.IsTabAvailable(SPRibbon.ListFormRibbonDispTabId))
{
  current.Visible = false;
}
```

How do I hide ribbon tabs on the list forms? Is there a way to check if the page is list form? How do I check if specific tab is available?

[image]

**Answer** : Used css to hide the ribbon.

Comment: Use this script in Master page. '<script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("s4-ribbonrow").style.display = "none";
    </script>'

Comment: @suren `s4-ribbonrow` hides the full ribbon. I just want to hide tabs. Is there any way i can put this code only on list forms.

Comment: Are you looking for this? [http://www.chaitumadala.com/2010/04/hide-sharepoint-2010-ribbon-in-list.html]

Comment: The methode in the link to hide ribbon is not feasible as we have many list forms. Need the change to be at one place and reflect everywhere.